# Nginx API configuration with unlimited parameters

Tags: api, rest, nginx

I'm trying to set up a quick temp API for a project i'm working on

My current nginx conf :

```
listen 80;
server_name app.domain.com

root /var/www/html/public;
index index.html index.php:

rewrite ^/api/v1/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /apiv1.php?class=$1method=$2? last;

location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

+ standard fpm config
```

While this works for urls like /api/v1/type/subtype ,

I need to be able to request to url in a format like this :

/api/v1/organisation/{id}/teams

/api/v1/organisations/{id}/teams/{id}

How can I get an unlimited amount of possible parameters in my url?

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to parse URL with PHP, not with Nginx. You can create a `location` that would handle all "/api/v1" requests and `proxy_pass` them to `apiv1.php`, which in turn would do all the rest.